# When mounting external disk in fstab via fuse.sshfs it requires password although identityfile is set

Tags: fstab, sshfs, fuse

Using Ubuntu 22.04. My `fstab` entry:

```
some_user@some_storagebox.com:~/somedir /mnt/volume fuse.sshfs defaults,allow_other,reconnect,_netdev,users,ServerAliveInterval=15,identityfile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa,uid=101,gid=101,ServerAliveCountMax=3 0 0
```

Check fstab line with:

```
mount /mnt/volume-1
```

storage requires to enter password although I'm using rsa key with `identityfile` parameter.

Could it be related with `uid`, `gid` parameters or any other. I'm lost.

UPDATE:
By testing @Nikita Kipriyanov answerI tried to connect via `ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa some_user@some_storagebox.com` and found that previously I connected via ssh with 23 port. Added it to fstab, but then mounting failed on

> ~/somedir

directory which was not found.
After adjusting it to

> /home/somedir

everything worked perfectly.

Updated fstab entry:

```
some_user@some_storagebox.com:/home/somedir /mnt/volume fuse.sshfs defaults,allow_other,reconnect,_netdev,users,ServerAliveInterval=15,port=23,identityfile=/root/.ssh/id_rsa,uid=101,gid=101,ServerAliveCountMax=3 0 0
```

Only one mind blowing thing, why mounted directory can go with a tilde and be found on mounting fstab with password and without port.

Comment: Can you `ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa some_user@some_storagebox.com`? Will it ask for the password? Check also authentication/security/audit logs on the server (where SSH logins are logged); maybe there is a problem with the authorized_keys file.

Comment: Thanks! By seeking you answer I found, that via ssh I connected with 23 port. Then I adjusted my fstab entry by adding port number. Then on mount fstab complains that ~/somedir is not found, after adjustin it to /home/somedir everything worked perfectly. Thanks! Only one mind blowing thing, why mounted directory can go with a tilde and be found on mounting fstab with password and without port.